# Tutorial on net surgery?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to replace the `"fc1000"` layer in a `NetModel`, what am I missing here:

```
net = NetModel["ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]
NetReplacePart[net, {
     "fc1000" -> LinearLayer[2],
     "prob" -> SoftmaxLayer[],
     "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"A", "B"}}]
 }]
```

[image]

I would love it if someone could write a nice tutorial on real-world applications of inserting/tweaking/moving layers for partial retraining.

Comment: I am on 11.2, and I get "SoftmaxLayer::argr: SoftmaxLayer called with 1 argument; 0 arguments are expected."

Comment: @MarcoB I changed it to just SoftmaxLayer[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so `NetReplacePart` won't work in this case, you need a `NetTake`:

```
res = NetModel["ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]
net = NetChain[{NetTake[res, {1, "flatten_0"}], LinearLayer[2], 
   SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"A", "B"}}]]
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to use ```NetAppend[NetDrop[res, -2],{"classify" -> LinearLayer[2], "probs" -> SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"A", "B"}}]]```.